# Search in an NSArray whose content are fetched CoreData objects by an specific object atribute

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've a `NSArray` that contains different `Exercise objects` that were fetched from `CoreData`.

In another method in my program I need to find an object whose property matches a criteria eg: `Exercise.exerciseName == @"bench press"` lets say I want to get the `Exercise Object` with the name of `bench press`.

I know I could achieve by doing the below code, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it in `objective-c` with a `predicate` or something like that.

```
for (Exercise*exercise in _exercises) {
    if( [exercise.exerciseName isEqualToString:@"bench press"] )
    {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray* filteredExercises = [_exercises filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"excerciseName == %@", @"bench press"]];
```